# Bash: Parameter Expansion | Parameter Transformation on List of Assoc.Array Keys

Tags: scripting, array, parameter

Is this possible(bash v5.0.3)?

I'd like to dynamically populate a select list using the keys of an associative array (for further code reuse & script automation). Some keys simply require whitespace. I seem to have isolated my issue to `choices="${!playlist_url[@]}"  # Need quoted key expansion here, but choices="${!playlist_url[@]@Q} does nothing"`

My script as it appears below displays a single select option with all the uploaders printing as a concatenation behind "1) ". Best I can accomplish is single quotes around the key dump into $choices with Quit outside of quotes i.e. `choices=("Quit ${choices@Q}")`

## Script

```
# Creates the array
declare -A playlist_url

# Sets the field separator to comma and reads in the uploader & url
## EXAMPLES: from ~/.config/youtube-dl/playlists-hcs7 ##
# UploaderName,https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=xx...xx
# Uploader Name,https://www/youtube.com/playlist?list=xx...xx
# Up Loader Name,https://www/youtube.com/playlist?list=xx...xx

while IFS=\, read -p "uploader,url" uploader url
do
    playlist_url[$uploader]="$url"
done <~/.config/youtube-dl/playlists-hcs7

#unset IFS  <--Ignore my trying to better understand the IFS
#IFS=       <--"      "
choices=${!playlist_url[@]}  # Need quoted key expansion here (I think!)
choices=("Quit ${choices}") # Prepending 'Quit' for case break below

clear

PS3="Make a selection: "

select option in "$choices";
do
    case $option in
        "Quit")
            echo "Exiting."
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Debug: $option"
            # Do stuff
            ;;
    esac
done
```

## Resources Used

- bash manpage
- countless rewordings in search engines
- Helpful [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985353)/[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12985178) of similar scope, dissimilar application.

Namely this edit within the linked answer:

> Edit: Almost 5 years later and since I answered this question, bash 4.4 has been released. This has the "${var@Q}" expansion which quotes the variable such that it can be parsed back by bash.

Comment: Are you looking for `choices=("Quit" "${!playlist_url[@]}")` and `select option in "${choices[@]}"`?

Comment: @muru This appears to clear my present roadblock. Attempting to mark as my answer. Many thanks!